# How to link my current user on my database with react native and firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to link my login with firebase to my database to firestore.

On my app i can actually log in me with google and the phone
[image]

Then i have to add more details for my user.
[image]

At this moment i used firestore to create the object of my user but i don't know how to connect my current user. My function succeed but my object doesn't seems connected to my current user ...

How i can do that ?

Also my function

```
createUser = () => {
      
        firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .add({
            NickName: this.state.NickName,
            Age: this.state.Age,
            City:this.state.City,
            Mail:this.state.Mail,
            MyTeam:[{
                Activity:"",
                City:"",
                Members:[{
                    Mail:"",
                    Pseudo:""
                }],
            Owner:true
            }]
        
            }).then ( ()=>{ }
               
            )
                .then(() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profil')
                
                })
                
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit different creating the user in the Firestore Database and retrieving current logged in User.
As you can see in the Google Firebase authentication (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users), you should check auth():

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

The best way, would be to observe the onAuthStateChanged:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
} else {
    // No user is signed in.
}});
```